# Why are my Google fonts not working?

Tags: google-font-api

It looks like my Google fonts are not working properly. My wordpress theme comes with a customized Googlefonts.php that uses this code to request the fonts:

```
foreach($googlefonts as $getfonts) {

if(!in_array($getfonts, $default)) {
        $customfont = str_replace(' ', '+', $getfonts). ':400,400italic,700,700italic|' . $customfont;
}
}

if($customfont != ''){
echo "<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" . substr_replace($customfont ,"",-1) . "&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
```

}

I do not understand how the Google fonts api works, I never used it in this way.

According to Firebug my call to the api returns a bad request. This is the URL that the above piece of code sends to Google right now:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese
```

Can someone explain to me why this is not working?

PS: Someone may think why are you requesting the same font so many times. This is because my theme has options to get different fonts for H1, H2, normal text, the menu, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [URL itself explains why it's not working](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trebuchet%20MS:400,400italic,700,700italic%7CTrebuchet%20MS:400,400italic,700,700italic%7CTrebuchet%20MS:400,400italic,700,700italic%7CTrebuchet%20MS:400,400italic,700,700italic%7CTrebuchet%20MS:400,400italic,700,700italic%7CTrebuchet%20MS:400,400italic,700,700italic%7CTrebuchet%20MS:400,400italic,700,700italic%7CTrebuchet%20MS:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese) - Google do not have a Trebuchet MS font.

Comment: Lol, then why does my theme add Trebuchet MS in the dropdown to choose from? Let me look into this :)

Comment: What? That link is malformed somehow, but if you actually paste the url in the url bar it works fine: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic|Trebuchet+MS:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese

Comment: Or at least it works fine on my (linux) computer today, maybe it didn't work previously, or only works with some user agents?